# document.getElementById("test").style.display="hidden" not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide my form when I click on the submit button. My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hide() {
        document.getElementById("test").style.display = "hidden";
    }
</script>
<form method="post" id="test">
    <table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
        <tr style="background:url(../images/nav.png) repeat-x; color:#fff; font-weight:bold"
        align="center">
            <td>Ample Id</td>
            <td>Find</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E8F8FF" style="color:#006">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ampid" id="ampid" value="<?php echo $_POST['ampid'];?>"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="image" src="../images/btnFind.png" id="find" name="find"
                onclick="javascript:hide();" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

But when I click on the "Find" button, that particular form is not being hidden.

Comment: Because `display` has no attribude `hidden`. Try `none`.

Comment: Tip: Read up on [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: And after you fix the "none" issue, the form submits so on the next page load, the form will be shown again...

Answer (score 61):

It should be either

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("test").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Second option will display some blank space where the form was initially present , where as the first option doesn't

Answer (score 16):

Set CSS display property to **none**.

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
```

Also, you **do not need** `javascript:` for the `onclick` attribute.

```
<input type="image" src="../images/btnFind.png" id="find" name="find" 
    onclick="hide();" />
```

Finally, make sure you **do not have** multiple elements with the **same ID**.

If your form goes nowhere, Phil suggested that you should prevent submission of the form. Simply `return false` in the **onsubmit** handler.

```
<form method="post" id="test" onsubmit="return false;">
```

If you want the form to post, but hide the div on subsequent page load, you will have to use server-side code to hide the element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
}
window.onload = function() {
    // if form was submitted, PHP will print the below, 
    //    which runs function hide() on page load
    <?= ($_POST['ampid'] != '') ? 'hide();' : '' ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: Might want to prevent the default action (form submit) from occurring too

Comment: But when the page navigates away (to the same page), you're not going to see the results of the script. In fact, I'd say that's exactly what the OP is seeing and assumes that the form is not being hidden.

Comment: it is working if i use onsubmit="return false;" but i want the result to be displayed also.. m not able to display results if i use onsubmit="rturn false"

Answer (score 15):

Using jQuery:

```
   $('#test').hide();
```

Using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display="none";
```

Threw an error "**Cannot set property 'display' of undefined**"

So, fix for this would be:

```
document.getElementById("test").style="display:none";
```

where your html code will look like this:

```
<div style="display:inline-block" id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `hidden` with `none`. See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this.

Most of the answers have correctly pointed out that style.display has no value called "hidden". It should be none.

If you want to use "hidden" the syntax should be as follows.

```
object.style.visibility="hidden"
```

The difference between the two is the visibility="hidden" property will only hide the contents of you  element but retain it position on the page. Whereas the display ="none" will hide your complete element and the rest of the elements on the page will fill that void created by it.

Check this [illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/sgMgS/1)

Answer (score 1):

its a block element, and you need to use `none`

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display="none"
```

`hidden` is used for `visibility`

Comment: Watch out for whacky quote characters in your answers (ie `“`) as people **will** copy and paste from here :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a class like 'hide'.

Follow the example here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList.

> document.getElementById("test").classList.add("anotherclass");

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `display = none`

value hidden is connected with attributet called `visibility`

so your code should look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide(){
document.getElementById("test").style.display="none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: @namratha put an alert into the function. I bet it isn't invoked. if you're using onclick event you don't need to write javascript:hide() simple hide(); is enough

Comment: i used alert and checked function is invoked but that form part is not hidding when i click on find button

Answer (score 0):

this should be it try it.

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display="none";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this....`div` container

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide(){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML.style.display="none";
}
</script>
<div id="test">
<form method="post" >

<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"  >
  <tr style="background:url(../images/nav.png) repeat-x; color:#fff; font-weight:bold" align="center">
    <td>Ample Id</td>
    <td>Find</td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E8F8FF" style="color:#006" >
    <td><input type="text" name="ampid" id="ampid" value="<?php echo $_POST['ampid'];?>" /></td>
   <td><input type="image" src="../images/btnFind.png" id="find" name="find" onclick="javascript:hide();"/></td>
   </tr>

</table>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display="none";
```

Through Jquery

```
$('#test').hide();
```