# How to hide div when you scroll to bottom and show it again when scroll up to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my scroller to hide when you come to bottom of page.
I wrote this code and it works fine:

```
<script>
document.onscroll = function() {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight) {
            document.getElementById("scroller").style.display='hide';
        }


    }
</script>
```

But now the scroller is hidden also when you go back to top.

I want to show #scroller again when user scroll back to top.

Comment: `$("#scroller").toggle(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY <= document.body.clientHeight)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18480502/9103599

Comment: or `document.getElementById("scroller").style.display =  window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight ? 'none':'block'`

Comment: Don't forget to debounce your eventhandler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an else case that display it:

```
if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight) {
     document.getElementById("scroller").style.display='none';
}
else{
     document.getElementById("scroller").style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: A ternary would be more elegant

Comment: @mplungjan But maybe the code is doing some other process that are not displayed in the question

Comment: Highly unlikely

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    document.onscroll = function() {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight) {
            document.getElementById("scroller").style.display='hide';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("scroller").style.display='block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A ternary would be more elegant - and it is none, not hide

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").scroll(function(){
        if($("div").scrollTop()==0)
            $("scroller").show();   
        else
               $("scroller").hide(); 
});
```

});

In JQuery you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $('#scroller').hide('slow');
   } 
   else if($(window).scrollTop()==0)
   {
          $('#scroller').show('slow');
   }
});
```